# GeckoDriver Selenium problem: how resolve without download anything?

Tags: java, selenium, bots

I'm creating my personal bot with Selenium and I want to export this project.
When I create my jar, send to my friends and they open it, the jar gets a Exception.

> java.lang.illegalstateexception the driver executable does not exist firefox

How can I resolve this? I did `System.setproprieties("..")`, but what if I don't want them to download gecko driver?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
"/Users/myuser/Downloads/geckodriver");
```

Comment: you can add webdriver  manager class to support your browser and resolve this

Comment: I understand, can be more exhaustive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linux/mac, the driver needs to be executable before using it for automation.
To make it executable, you can go to the path of that driver and then use `chmod +x` command.
In your case, commands would be like:

```
cd /Users/myuser/Downloads
chmod +x geckodriver
```

And then you can run your code, it would work fine.